# Edit the info.plist of an app and still be able to run it on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, code-signing, dock

I would like to be able to edit the `Info.plist` file inside an app and still be able to run it. Specifically, I am trying to hide apps from the dock by adding the key `LSUIElement = True` to the app.

After a lot of googling and trying, this is what I have tried:

A) I tried modifying the plist file and it works great right away. However, after a reboot, there is a finder popup that says "The Application ... can't be opened."
From what I gathered, this is because the app is signed and after modifying it, macOS Monterey doesn't allow me to run it anymore. Is there a way to remove the signature just for myself and still be able to run it? Maybe with `codesign --remove-signatur`? Or can I sign it without being an apple developer and having to pay the ~90$?

B) A workaround that i found could be to use ActiveDock 2. It replaces the mac dock by a custom one. However, i had some buggy behavior and slow animations which drove me nuts.

Thanks a lot for your help! And please let me know if you need any other info (first post, still learning...)

Other info:

- macOS Monterey 12.5
- MacBook Air M2